# d3 stacked bar with unusual data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i want to create a stacked bar chart, but not the usual way with series, who get stacked.

exact data example:

```
[  
{"issue":19,"created_at":"2017-01-06T14:24:04.247Z","time":"00:30:00"},
{"issue":18,"created_at":"2017-01-06T14:24:04.247Z","time":"02:00:00"},
{"issue":18,"created_at":"2017-01-07T14:24:04.247Z","time":"00:10:00"},
{"issue":19,"created_at":"2017-01-07T14:24:04.247Z","time":"00:10:00"},
{"issue":17,"created_at":"2017-01-07T14:24:04.247Z","time":"02:00:00"},
{"issue":17,"created_at":"2017-01-07T14:24:04.247Z","time":"06:00:00"},
{"issue":17,"created_at":"2017-01-08T14:24:04.247Z","time":"06:00:00"},
{"issue":17,"created_at":"2017-01-09T14:24:04.247Z","time":"06:00:00"},
{"issue":17,"created_at":"2017-01-09T14:24:04.247Z","time":"00:30:00"},
{"issue":18,"created_at":"2017-01-10T14:24:04.247Z","time":"00:10:00"},
{"issue":19,"created_at":"2017-01-10T14:24:04.247Z","time":"02:00:00"},
{"issue":17,"created_at":"2017-01-10T14:24:04.247Z","time":"06:00:00"},
{"issue":19,"created_at":"2017-01-10T14:24:04.247Z","time":"02:00:00"},
{"issue":19,"created_at":"2017-01-11T14:24:04.247Z","time":"00:10:00"}
]
```

I want to create now a stacked-bar chart for the last seven days, where values(time field) are stacked for each day and coloured by id(issue).

The Problem is all examples i found are doing series stacking

I have different amounts of values per day:  0 <= #values(day)

can someone show me a short example (http://jsfiddle.net/qbmy76on/3/) of getting a stacked bar out of this data with d3(value could also be a simple integer value, like in the following example)

with Charts.js i realized a Prototype(with minutes), but i want to switch to d3 for future Features.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQy2R.png

Comment: Just a tip: use `:`, not `=`, to make this a valid object, and wrap the objects into an array.

Comment: yeah, just some example data, that is not the problem.. i just don't know how to realize such a case elegant in d3.

Comment: this is the data structure i have right now in my js file: http://i.imgur.com/tljd89p.png

Comment: In that case, please paste your exact array, otherwise people will lose time trying a solution which will not work.

Comment: okay, done, let's hope somebody can show me an example fiddle or something

Answer (score 0):

i have now the following data and want to plot it stacked(values.object.time) per day:

```
[
{
"key": "2017-01-07",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-07",
    "time": 10
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-07",
    "time": 360
  }
]
},
{
"key": "2017-01-08",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 20,
    "created_at": "2017-01-08",
    "time": 360
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-08",
    "time": 360
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-08",
    "time": 10
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-08",
    "time": 360
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-08",
    "time": 360
  }
]
},
{
"key": "2017-01-09",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 20,
    "created_at": "2017-01-09",
    "time": 120
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 22,
    "created_at": "2017-01-09",
    "time": 120
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-09",
    "time": 30
  }
]
},
{
"key": "2017-01-10",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 20,
    "created_at": "2017-01-10",
    "time": 360
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-10",
    "time": 360
  }
]
},
{
"key": "2017-01-11",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 21,
    "created_at": "2017-01-11",
    "time": 360
  }
]
},
{
"key": "2017-01-12",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 20,
    "created_at": "2017-01-12",
    "time": 120
  }
]
},
{
"key": "2017-01-13",
"values": [
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 22,
    "created_at": "2017-01-13",
    "time": 30
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 20,
    "created_at": "2017-01-13",
    "time": 60
  },
  {
    "user": 1,
    "issue": 20,
    "created_at": "2017-01-13",
    "time": 10
  }
]
}
]
```

to get something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7oCk.png
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vt3990yr/26/